# Why is CORS blocking CountAPI?

Tags: html, cors

Recently I have been developing a React website and wanted to include a simple counter API to display the number of visits to the website.

After watching some tutorial videos for this API: https://countapi.xyz/ , the instructions said that I need to generate a namespace and key for my website using the following link:

[https://api.countapi.xyz/create?namespace={name of your website}&enable_reset=1](https://api.countapi.xyz/create?namespace=%7Bname%20of%20your%20website%7D&enable_reset=1)

It is mentioned that the name of the website can be anything you want it to be.

If I edit this link to feature the name of my website, it does not load. The result should look like this:

[image]

This is the tutorial video I used: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTHrtiMEjk0&t

The comment section suggests that a change was made around 4 months ago to how the API works, but I am unable to find any mention of this

Furthermore, when I visit the API website, it seems broken as if the API isnt working for them either:

[image]

When inspecting i found this:

[image]

I managed to use this code on their website and also received the same CORS error:

```
  import countapi from 'countapi-js';

countapi.visits().then((result) => {
    console.log(result.value);
});
```

I have never heard of CORS but from what I understand after some research is that it is blocking my access to the backend server...

I was wondering if this is an issue on my end, and have no clue on how to go about solving this.
One solution I found was for if you actually own the server which is blocking you, but obviously I dont think thats the case here...
I should mention I am not hosting my website currently, I am running it from localhost, but others have also done this and it worked for them in the tutorials.